# How can i Solve this Code of creating ISO-8385 parser in Java?

Tags: iso8583

Bellow is my code.

```
     for (int i : Utility.getFieldPosList(hexBitmap)) {
        IsoValue mtl = this.parserConfig.get(i);
        if (mtl == null) {
            break;
        }
        field = parseField(mtl, isoMessageFields);
        mtl.setValue(field);
        responseMessage.setField(i, mtl);
        if(mtl.getIsoType() == IsoType.LLVAR){
            isoMessageFields = isoMessageFields.substring(field.length() + 2);
        }else if(mtl.getIsoType() == IsoType.LLLVAR){
            isoMessageFields = isoMessageFields.substring(field.length() + 3);
        }else{
            isoMessageFields = isoMessageFields.substring(field.length());
        }
        sb.append("\nin[ " + i + " ]<" + field + ">");
    }
```

I am not getting the exact value of i, so in this circumstances, I need some suggestion .

Comment: Impossible to know why i is wrong without the code of your `Utility.getFieldPosList` method and what there is in your hexBitmap variable